# find text string in XML

Tags: javascript, jquery

**How would i find the xml node that has a certain text value?**

example i want to do something like this which is not working:

```
var xml = "<data><itemB>more data</itemB><itemC>yes, more data</itemC><itemA>some data</itemA></data>";

var searchString = "more data";

var foundin = $(xml + ":contains(" + searchString + ")");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke the [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector with the root XML element as its context:

```
var foundin = $(":contains(" + searchString + ")", xml);
```

You can see the results in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ksALg/).

Answer (score 1):

Try $(xml).children('*:contains("more data")')

Answer (score 1):

These guys beat me to it, but here is the example I made.

```
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var xml = "<data><itemB>more data</itemB><itemC>yes, more data</itemC><itemA>some data</itemA></data>";
            var query = "more data";
            $(":contains(" + query + ")", xml).each(function(){
                alert(this.localName); //show node name
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**Edit**
I'm assuming you're trying to get to the xml node with the query text. You probably want to use nodeName instead of localName for better IE support.